# Journal paper published without correction of errors

Tags: publications, journals, errors-erratum

I notified a journal prior to publication that there were errors in a paper. This was submitted around 3 weeks ago, the review process was quick. On Thursday I was given 24 hours to make a list of corrections to the final version I was sent. These were done but then I noticed a few errors after and emailed a revised version along with a document outlining and explaining changes. I had an email today to say the paper has been published (early access version) but its the version with the errors.

The email states changes to text can no longer be made. But they published this after I notified them of errors. This seems to have been rushed.

I emailed back within a few minutes of getting this email today but I expect I won't get a response until Monday now, so I have a weekend of worrying. I didn't expect the paper to be published at a weekend, it makes communication more difficult.

What is likely to happen now? Are changes likely or will these be denied?

I didn't see the version after they made edits, which their communication led me to believe I would, particularly as they were asking me to make a lot of changes. Nonetheless I emailed them before this was published to correct errors. It puts me off publishing with that particular journal again.

Comment: What kind of error are you referring to?

Comment: An error in a results table due to a calculation error in a spreadsheet, results hence a bit higher than they should be although still seemed reasonable so hadn't picked it up at first, the correct result does align with a published one for this. It isn't part of the main findings of the paper, its some additional detail. I notified the journal in good time to get it changed and it would have taken a few mins of editing. Otherwise a spelling mistake in a section title which appeared after the journal had done some edits then sent it back to me and I missed it at first, I'm dyslexic.

Comment: The person who did the seemingly rushed final edit on a Saturday morning is someone I have had no contact with before.

Answer (score 3):

You have probably done all you can do at the moment. What the journal is willing to do is up to them.

But it may be that the "early access" version can't/won't be changed but a later *final* version will have the corrections.

Longer term, if you still have issues with the errors it may be possible to at least have an errata page published.

Comment: Indeed, many journals post ‘early access’ in-proof versions, clearly marked as such.

Answer (score 0):

If an error/mistake may affect the results/interpretation of the study (based on the comments) it often cannot simply changed without the editor and maybe even the reviewers' input.

Whether such an error is small and not part of the main findings, and of no effect on the outcome of the study, isn't something a layout editor is allowed/willing to decide.

Let's hope the editor catches your request on time and can have a look at it before final publication - he/she will have to decide whether you can just change it, or whether it needs to go via the reviewers again (which might be quick if it's small and unimportant). Otherwise you can discuss with the editor whether you need to submit an errata or retract the paper (unlikely, given your description).

Comment: The first response after submission was comments from 4 reviewers and major changes needed that I had 10 days to do. I did those and made some additional changes. A few days after that I was given 24 hours to look over the version the journal had edited. I was expecting reviewers to have looked over it again but that doesn't seem to have happened so I doubt they would decide to refer this to reviewers at this stage. This journal doesn't allow papers to be withdrawn.